# $f^2$ integrable and $f$ is not

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm  trying to find an example of a function that is not Lebesgue integrable but $f^2$ is integrable.
The problem I am trying to solve includes the converse for which i gave: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ or the characteristic function of $(-n,n)$ as examples.

Comment: Hint: $(-1)^2 = 1$

Comment: What's the domain? Did you try $f(x) = 1/x$?

Comment: $1/x$ is not integrable an neither is $\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: $1/x^2$ *is* integrable on $[1, \infty]$. This is why I'm asking you about the domain.

Comment: I am thinking about the dirichlet function but that would only work in a finite interval

Comment: The domain is R

Comment: Then consider $\dfrac{\chi_{[1, \infty]}}{x}$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11944/discussion-between-user114032-and-ayman-hourieh)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't join chat at the moment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways for a function to be not integrable: It could be non-measurable, or the absolute value could have an infinite integral. To find examples for the latter, notice that $|f(x)|^2<|f(x)|$ whenever $0<|f(x)|<1$, so a good strategy is to look at functions with values in $(0,1)$. (An example is already given in another answer.)

If you wish to go for the non-measurability angle, the hint $(-1)^2=1$ given by John in the comments is invaluable. Can you think of a non-measurable $f$ for which $f^2=1$? I am sure I can …

Comment: The dirichlet function

Comment: I would go for $2\chi_E-1$ where $E$ is a nonmeasurable set.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=x^{-1}\mathbf 1_{[1,+\infty)}(x)$$